# Selecting records by applying additional conditions until records are found in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Let's suppose that we have a list of orders for different addresses.
Each order record has its own status and service date.
Status is an int enumeration, e.g. "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10", where "10" means submitted, "2" is pending, "3" is approved, "6" is completed etc.
We have a functionality for re-using content of previous orders on creation of a new order. For this purpose we need to find the latest order record that has the same address and service type as the current order.
But there is one more thing. 
We need to find the latest record based on order status. First of all, we are interested in order that has 'completed' status. If there is no such order, we want to look for order with 'approved' status. Then 'submitted' and so on.

So far I've come up with the next solution:

```
declare @date datetime = '2016-10-18';  
declare @serviceType varchar(20) = 'delivery';  
declare @zipCode int = 99999;  

WITH cte AS (  
  SELECT * FROM Order AS O  
  WHERE O.serviceDate <= @date AND  
  O.serviceType = @serviceType AND  
  O.zipCode = @zipCode)  

/* find order for content re-using */  
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM cte  
WHERE status =   
  CASE   
  WHEN 0 < (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM cte  
  WHERE Status = 6) /* completed */  
  THEN 6  
  WHEN 0 < (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM cte  
  WHERE Status = 3) /* approved */  
  THEN 3  
  WHEN 0 < (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM cte  
  WHERE Status = 2) /* pending */  
  THEN 2  
  WHEN 0 < (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM cte  
  WHERE Status = 10) /* submitted */  
  THEN 10    
  END  
ORDER BY serviceDate DESC;
```

Is there any better (more optimized) solution?

Comment: There is certainly some room for improvement here but it is impossible to offer any code without any context of your tables. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Which has the greater precedence in selecting the "latest" order, the serviceDate or the order Status? For example, if an order from yesterday has a "4" Status (Completed) and an order from today has a "3"   Status (Pending), which order should be selected as the "latest"?

Comment: @JohnH, Order status has greater precedence.

Comment: I've edited enumeration list in topic description to emphasize that statuses are not sorted by their precedence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with the next solution after some thoughts.

```
select top 1 *, 
  CASE 
      WHEN so.WP_GenericStatus = 6 THEN 1
      WHEN so.WP_GenericStatus = 3 THEN 2
      WHEN so.WP_GenericStatus = 2 THEN 3
      WHEN so.WP_GenericStatus = 10 THEN 4
      ELSE 5
  END AS 'Priority'  
  FROM Order AS O
  WHERE O.serviceDate <= @date and 
  O.serviceType = @serviceType and
  O.zipCode = @zipCode 
  ORDER BY 'Priority' ASC, serviceDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your query returns correct result and the correct precedence is 6,3,2,1,9,10. Change the order accordingly.
Try below for a cleaner code.

```
DECLARE @date datetime = '2016-10-18';  
DECLARE @serviceType varchar(20) = 'delivery';  
DECLARE @zipCode int = 99999;  

    SELECT  TOP (1) *  
    FROM [dbo].[Order] AS O  
    WHERE O.serviceDate <= @date AND  
          O.serviceType = @serviceType AND  
          O.zipCode = @zipCode AND  
          Status  IN (SELECT  Status  FROM [dbo].[Order] M GROUP BY (M.Status  ) HAVING COUNT(*)>=1 )    

          ORDER BY CASE WHEN Status  = 6 THEN 1
              WHEN Status  =2 THEN 2
              when Status  = 3THEN 3
              when Status  = 1 THEN 4
              when Status  = 9 THEN 5
               when Status  = 10 THEN 6 END ASC,
         serviceDate  DESC
```

Comment: the difficulty is order statuses enumeration is more complex than I've mentioned in my example. Statuses are not sorted by its precedence, therefore I need to select orders with statuses = 6 in the first place, then look for orders with statuses 2, 3, 1, 10, 9 respectively.

Comment: In your edited code sample you have considered only 4 statuses 6,3,2 and 10 respectively. But as I understood your precedence should be 6,2,3,1,10 and 9 which is contradictory to your example. Before finding a solution I like to clarify the exact precedence first.

Comment: Yes, you've understood correctly. I've provided only 4 statuses in my example for simplicity.

Comment: Its better to provide the complete example. In your example order status 3 is higher than order status 2. But in the comment its wise versa. What is the correct precedence?

Comment: Correct precedence is "6,2,3,1,10,9", but it does not matter as long as we understand that this enumeration is not sorted in any way.

Comment: I have edited the answer to be matched with the given order precedence. Hope it'll help you.

Comment: thanks. Your query works if "else" clause is added to "case" sorting condition. Also, "Status IN (SELECT..." row is not necessary. The query works perfectly without it.

Comment: Glad you've found it useful.